# How do I get a user field from an entity reference?

Tags: entities, rules

[image: Rule setup]
[image: Fetch Entity by Property]
I'm working with the Twilio module to create a Rule that will send out an SMS message when a user creates a specific piece of content.  Here's how I've got things laid out at the moment.

1. I have a content type called Office (*field_office*), which contains the regional office name (imported from LDAP, but that probably doesn't matter.)
2. I have an entity reference user profile field called *field_user_office* that links to the Office content type.
3. I created a content type called Blast Message with an entity reference field called *field_office_sms* which also links to the Office content type.  When a user wants to create an SMS they create one of these nodes and select one or more offices to send to.

When I set up my rule I'm not seeing the fields exposed as I expected.  I tried adding two Entity has field conditions, *Parameter: Entity: [node], Field: field_office_sms* and *Parameter: Entity: [node], Field: field_mobile_phone*, the last of which is the actual mobile number saved in the users' accounts.

How do I navigate from the original content (Blast Message) through the Offices, then to the specific Users who are linked to that office, and ultimately retrieve their mobile phone numbers?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the action: Fetch entity by property.

1. Condition: Entity has field > node: field_office_sms
2. Fetch entity by property > User > Property: field_user_office > Value: node: field_office_sms:nid
3. Loop: List: [entity-fetched]
4. Action: Send SMS > list-item: field_mobile_phone

Comment: Interesting -- though I'm running into a problem with the Fetch entity by property action in that I don't have nid as an option.  For node:field_office_sms my options are 0, 1, 2, and 3.  Also, my Send SMS action doesn't have list-item as a choice as I get (only site, node, and entity-fetched, and entity-fetched has the same 0, 1, 2, and 3 options.)

Comment: You have 0,1,2 and 3 because it's an unlimited field. So you have to go into 0:nid as it's the first (and only?) option. When you do the fetch, you can do the loop and get list items.

Comment: Unfortunately trying to force node:field-office-sms:0:nid gives the error "The data type of the configured argument does not match the parameter's value requirement." and it won't save.

Comment: Have you made any progress? Some screenshots could help.. Also try using the action, "convert value" to integer. I've had to do that before.

Comment: No luck so far, but screenshots added.  I tried adding "convert data type" as I don't see "convert value", but I'm not sure what to do with that once it's in place.